# Best practice about detecting DOM element exist in D3

Tags: d3.js

All:

In D3, it often uses `.data().enter().append()` to reuse existing elements rather than remove everything and add them, but on the other hand, when the DOM structure is very deep, it will involve a lot of this detect(one for every level),   I wonder if there is a good way to detect until which level, I need to start use `.enter()` rather than from the top level?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand your question, you could be asking about one of two possible things. Either:

1. you're asking about how to use d3's `.data()` binding method to compute the three sets (enter, update, exit) *at multiple levels of a dom hierarchy;* or
2. you already know how to do #1, and are asking about how to NOT do it (i.e. skip calling `.data()`) in certain cases in order to really optimize performance.

If the question is #1, then check out [this tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) on working with nested selection by  passing a function into the **first** argument of `.data()`.

If the question is #2, then you're taking a risk. By that I mean that you're risking spending a whole lot of time and effort to optimize an aspect of your code that's probably far from being the slowest part of the program. Usually, it's the browser's rendering that's the slowest, while the data binding is quite fast. In fact, following the nested selections pattern from #1 *is* likely the most effective way to optimize, because it eliminates unnecessary appending to - and re-rendering of - the DOM.

If you really want to do #2 anyway, then I think the way to start is by implementing it using nested selections from #1, and then adding some sort of `if` statement at every level of the hierarchy that decides whether it's ok to skip calling the `.data()` method. For that, you have to examine the incoming data vs the outgoing data and deciding whether they're still equal or not. However, since *deciding whether things are still equal* is roughly what d3's `.data()` method does, then your optimization of it would have to do even less. Perhaps one way to achieve that level of optimization would involve using immutable data structures, because that's a way to quickly test equality of two nested data structures (that's basically how things work in React.js). It sounds complicated though. That's why I say it's a risk....

There may be another approach, in which you analyze the incoming vs outgoing data and determine which branches of the data hierarchy have changed and then pinpoint the equivalent location in the DOM and use d3 `.data()` locally within those changed DOM nodes. That sounds even more complex and ambiguous. So to get more help with that on, you'd have to create something like a jsFiddle that recreates your specific scenario.